# Can I replace existing ram from PC3-10600U-9-10-B0 to PC3-10600U-9-11-B1

Tags: memory, ddr3

My desktop motherboard (Q65H2-AD) specifies that it supports: Dual Channel DDR3 1333 MHz non-ECC, un-buffered memory

The ram I am using has a model number PC3-10600U-9-10-B0

Can I replace it with this ram I can find: PC3-10600U-9-11-B1

the difference is the "9-XX-xx" part

Does this matter or it will not work as good?

Thanks.

I

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Your motherboard is compatible with the RAM module that you have found.

What is important is:

- Which RAM type your motherboar supports (DDR3 vs DDR4)
- Frequency and size